# reverse serialize() -jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jsonserializer

I sent my data (json) for an ajax request with this code;

```
var formdata = $("#customForm").serialize();

            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formdata,
```

In the php file, there is possible reverse the serialize?

or i need to make  something like that: `$pass = $_POST['pass'];` for all fields?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you are headed in the right direction with your "or" statement.  The data should be available in the $_POST array without needing to "deserialize" anything.

**EDIT**

Try to name your input fields so that they all come into the post variable as an array:

```
<input name="myformdata[first_name]" id="first_name" />
<input name="myformdata[last_name]" id="last_name" />
```

Then in the post array you can access all the form data like:

```
<?php $form_data_array = $_POST['myformdata']; ?>
```

Comment: @scott, the problem is the number of variables.

Comment: name your input fields so that all come into one array. I will edit my post as an example.

Comment: I think this is what you want.  Are you looking to reduce the number of variables once the data is in PHP?  Maybe I need some clarification on what you need.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: thanks scott. i think that you understand what i pretend. i simple want to avoid a list of variables like: $pass = $_POST['name']; $pass = $_POST['adress']; $pass = $_POST['country'];...for twenty variables

Comment: I think this should work for you then. Are you able to give it a try? Post a comment if you still have trouble and I will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try PHP's [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function:

```
extract($_POST);
```

**Example**:

```
$_POST = array('var_1' => 1234, 'var_2' => 'another variable');

extract($_POST);

echo $var_1.' '.$var_2;
```

**Outputs**:

> 1234 another variable

**Applied to Your Situation**:

extract($_POST);

Would result in whatever `key => value` pairs present in the `$_POST` array being extracted into variables.

Like doing `$pass = $_POST['pass']` on all variables in the `$_POST` array.

**Explanation**:

`extract` will import variables from an array into the current symbol table.

It checks each key to see whether it has a valid variable name. It also checks for collisions with existing variables in the symbol table.

From [PHP Docs (extract)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: but if i sent a serializeArray(); i need to get the values in the php file. So what you sugest have the same problem $_POST = array('var_1' => $_POST['pass']); . i need to make the same for all varibales

Comment: No, it is an example, in your case you could simply do `extract($_POST);` - nothing else. My intention with this example was simply to show you some code that can run and get a similar result.

Comment: ok, i understand, in this case i only use one time POST and no twenty $_POST['pass']. Thanks, good point

Comment: Yes, so long as you have some way of knowing what variables are put into the `$_POST` array :). Also, note that without a second parameter, `extract` will *overwrite* any variables that have already been declared with the same name! See the php docs for more info on possible second parameters for this function.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. You just need to acces like `$pass = $_POST['pass']` :).

Comment: but i have more than twenty fields... Normally for one, two or three variables, ok, but for twenty is a bit boring

Comment: its always boring.. but you can use `$_POST` variable to anywhere.